# How do i sum a list of items by code(or any field)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that has a list of another object in it. i.e Object1 contains `List<Object2>`.

Assuming this is the definition of object 2:

```
public class Object2
{
    string code,
    string name,
    decimal amount
}
```

I want to be a able to make a list2 from the list whose value will contain what something similar to what a `select name, code, sum(amount) group by code` kinda statement could have given me

this is what i did but it didnt contain what i needed on passing through.

```
var newlist = obj2List.GroupBy(x => x.code)
                      .Select(g => new { Amount = g.Sum(x => x.amount) });
```

I want code and name in the new list just like the sql statement above.

Comment: In SQL, you cannot select <name> if you group by <code>, you have to select an aggregate on <name> like 'min(name)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
var newlist = obj2List.GroupBy(x => x.code)
                      .Select(g => new
                      {
                          Code = g.First().code,
                          Name = g.First().name,
                          Amount = g.Sum(x => x.amount)
                      });
```

This groups the items by `code` and creates an anonymous object for each group, taking the code and name of first item of the group. (I assume that all items with the same code also have the same name.)

Comment: Don and Tim's answer also solved my problem.I accepted this as answer based on the fact that it came earlier and also solved my issue

Comment: Side-note, the `Code = g.First().code` is unnecessary since you already have grouped by `code`. So you just need to use `g.Key`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are grouping by code and not by name you'd have to choose something for name from the list, perhaps with First() or Last() or something.

```
var newlist = obj2List.GroupBy(x => x.code).Select(g => new {
                           Code = g.Key, 
                           Name = g.First().name, 
                           Amount = g.Sum(x => x.amount)
               });
```

Comment: Thanks...i appreciate your help.turns out i dont even require the name.code and amount was enough for my need

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = Object1.Obj2List
    .GroupBy(obj2 => obj2.code)
    .Select(g => new { 
        Names  = string.Join(",", g.Select(obj2.name)),
        Code   = g.Key,
        Amount = g.Sum(obj2 => obj2.Amount)
 });
```

Since you group by code only you need to aggregate the name also in some way. I have used `string.Join` to create a string like `"Name1,Name2,Name3"` for each code-group.

Now you could consume the query for example with a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}  Names: {1}  Amount: {2}"
        , x.Code, x.Names, x.Amount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the LINQ Extension Methods `.GroupBy()` and `.Select()`  you could also use a pure LINQ statement which is way easier to read if you come from a SQL Background.

```
        var ls = new List<Object2>();
        var newLs = from obj in ls
                    group obj by obj.code into codeGroup
                    select new { code = codeGroup.Key, amount = codeGroup.Sum(s => s.amount) };
```